# How do I store an account's Username/Pass in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

In my programming class I've been asked to create a class of type 'User'. Of course, every user must have a username/password. But, my professor says it's not wise to have them as class variables. Instead, he wants us to create a dictionary to store the username/pass.

That's fine, but say a user goes to log in. Sure I can find the dictionary entry for the username, and even check the password, but then where do I find the actual User object that it's linked to? That is to say, how do I link the string in the dictionary to its corresponding User object?

Comment: Dictionaries can store objects too!

Answer (score 0):

You could define a User object and create a dictionary property.

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, user, pass):
        self.username_and_password = {"username": user, "password": pass}
```

Then, you could access the username and password by using the expression `self.username_and_password["username"]` to access the username in any method of the class.